# How to properly add search query param to url containing hash in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to add a base url and query parameters to each link:

```
function buildURL(relativePath) {
    var url = new URL('http://example.com/' + relativePath);
    url.searchParams.set('utm_source', 'app');
    return url.toString(); 
}
```

It works fine for most cases:

```
buildURL('search')
"http://example.com/search?utm_source=app"

buildURL('search?q=query&page=2')
"http://example.com/search?q=query&page=2&utm_source=app"
```

The problem starts when I add an anchor:

```
buildURL('search#anchor')
"http://example.com/search?utm_source=app#anchor"

buildURL('search#anchor?q=query')
"http://example.com/search?utm_source=app#anchor?q=query"
```

This is not a valid URL with an anchor.

**Any ideas on how to overcome that using URL?**

**EDIT**

The expected outcome is adding the query params *after* the anchor

```
 buildURL('search#anchor')
"http://example.com/search#anchor?utm_source=app"

buildURL('search#anchor?q=query')
"http://example.com/search#anchor?utm_source=app?q=query"
```

```js
function buildURL(relativePath) {
    var url = new URL('http://example.com/' + relativePath);
    url.searchParams.set('utm_source', 'app');
    return url.toString(); 
}

console.log(buildURL("search"));
console.log(buildURL("search?q=query&page=1"));
console.log(buildURL("search#anchor"));
console.log(buildURL("search#anchor?q=query"));
```

Comment: What is the expected output for  3rd and 4th case?

Comment: Is the expected outcome `http://example.com/search?q=query&utm_source=app#anchor` ?

Comment: search#.....?... is not canonical URL formatting

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass in a hash in the search params.

But if you must, you can detect the hash, split it from the parameter, set the search param and add the hash

```js
function buildURL(relativePath) {
    var hash = "";
    if (relativePath.indexOf("#")!=-1) {
      var parts = relativePath.split("#");
      hash = encodeURIComponent(parts[1]); // optionally handle ? in the hash part
      relativePath=parts[0];
    } 
    var url = new URL('http://example.com/' + relativePath);
    url.searchParams.set('utm_source', 'app');
    if (hash) url.hash=hash;
    return url.toString(); 
}

console.log(buildURL("search"));
console.log(buildURL("search?q=query&page=1"));
console.log(buildURL("search#anchor"));
console.log(buildURL("search#anchor?q=query"));
```

Comment: Hey, the anchor is still appended after the qp. Also, the existing query is encoded.

Comment: Your question is incomplete - please add what your expected output is

Answer (score 0):

This should work.. **Pass the hash after the query params**

```js
function buildURL(path) {
  var relativePath = path.split('#')
  var url = new URL('http://example.com/' + relativePath[0]);
  url.searchParams.set('utm_source', 'app');
  url.hash = relativePath[1] ? relativePath[1] : ''
  return url.toString();
}

console.log(buildURL("search"));
console.log(buildURL("search?q=query&page=1"));
console.log(buildURL("search#anchor"));
console.log(buildURL("search#anchor?q=query"));
console.log(buildURL("searchr?q=query&q2=query2#anchor"));
```